# IST to EST Time Conversion In Java

Tags: java, datetime, datetimeoffset

I have a Date field in Java in IST Time. I want to convert the same to EST Time and the output should be as a Date Type only. I am able to accomplish the same using the below piece of code:-

```
SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
dateTimeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
String estTime = timeFormat.format(date);
date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(estTime);
```

The problem with the above piece of code is that though the date is converted in EST Time, the Time Zone is still showing as IST and not EST. The rest of the date is converted perfectly fine. Is there any way to explicitly set the time Zone To EST in the Date Field.Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

-Subhadeep

Comment: `dateTimeFormat` is an unused variable in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` class is time-zone agnostic. Basically, it is always based on GMT although when it is printed it uses the current system time zone to adjust it.

However, `Calendar` is time-zone specific. See [Calendar.setTimeZone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29).

Consider:

```
   Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
   cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
   cal.setTime(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` etc.) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

### Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.now();
        System.out.println(instant);

        ZonedDateTime zdtIndia = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta"));
        ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));

        System.out.println(zdtIndia);
        System.out.println(zdtNewYork);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-05-19T21:08:54.241341Z
2021-05-20T02:38:54.241341+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]
2021-05-19T17:08:54.241341-04:00[America/New_York]
```

[`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline. The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### Solution using legacy API:

The `java.util.Date` object is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time in the JVM's timezone, calculated from this milliseconds value. If you need to print the date-time in a different timezone, you will need to set the timezone to `SimpleDateFormat` and obtain the formatted string from it.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(date);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS[zzzzz]");

        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
        String dtIndia = sdf.format(date);

        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
        String dtNewYork = sdf.format(date);

        System.out.println(dtIndia);
        System.out.println(dtNewYork);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Wed May 19 22:16:08 BST 2021
2021-05-20T02:46:08.024[India Standard Time]
2021-05-19T17:16:08.024[Eastern Daylight Time]
```

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Should you add `z` for time-zone pattern in your `SimpleDateFormat` pattern?

So, it should be `DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss z")`. I changed your code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    dateTimeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
    Date date = new Date();

    System.out.println(dateTimeFormat.format(date)); // this print IST Timezone

    DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));

    String estTime = timeFormat.format(date);
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(estTime);

    System.out.println(timeFormat.format(date)); // this print EDT Timezone currently (on March)
}
```

In last print statement, current date format is printed with **EDT Timezone** (Eastern Daylight Time). Maybe because of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone).

Comment: Not working with Z parameter. The rest of the date is now coming in IST as well :(

Comment: Even if with lower case (`z`)? It is because uppercase (`Z`) is only print relative time to GMT like `-0400`.

Comment: Tried with small z only...Typo in the first reply :(

Comment: Are you use framework? Sorry, I cannot figure much. My code above is tested by creating a simple java application.

Comment: @WayanWiprayoga How to get a EDT timezone Date object from this?

Answer (score 0):

The correct [answer by John B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15477276/642706) explains that java.util.Date seems to have a time zone but does not. Its `toString` method applies your JVM's default time zone when generating the string representation.

That is one of many reasons to avoid java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java. Avoid them. Instead use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the java.time package built into Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310).

Here is some example code in Joda-Time 2.3.

```
String input = "01/02/2014 12:34:56";
DateTimeFormatter formatterInput = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" );
DateTimeZone timeZoneIndia = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTime dateTimeIndia = formatterInput.withZone( timeZoneIndia ).parseDateTime( input );

DateTimeZone timeZoneNewYork = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" );
DateTime dateTimeNewYork = dateTimeIndia.withZone( timeZoneNewYork );

DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeIndia.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTimeIndia: " + dateTimeIndia );
System.out.println( "dateTimeNewYork: " + dateTimeNewYork );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
```

When run…

```
input: 01/02/2014 12:34:56
dateTimeIndia: 2014-01-02T12:34:56.000+05:30
dateTimeNewYork: 2014-01-02T02:04:56.000-05:00
dateTimeUtc: 2014-01-02T07:04:56.000Z
```